# GDAL and Geospatial PDF on Windows

Tags: gdal, pdf

GDAL 1.8 now supports reading [GeospatialPDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geospatial_PDF), see [pdf format description page](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_pdf.html). Using it depends on the [poppler pdf library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poppler_%28software%29). What is the smoothest route to getting gdal and geospatial pdf working on Windows?

UPDATE: I mean getting the gdal *utilities*, the end user programs not the just the programming libraries.

Comment: +1 Because I have not figured out how to get GDAL 1.8 working on Windows, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This answer is outdated.  The link no longer works.**

Tamas Szkerest provides daily GDAL builds for Windows.  These might be another option.

http://vbkto.dyndns.org/sdk/

Comment: thanks Howard, this worked out of the box. And welcome to GIS.se :)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from building the current (dev) 1.8 version from source yourself (including all dependencies) I think your best bet would be to ask nicely at the [gdal-dev](http://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/gdal-dev/) mailing list if someone could provide you with a Windows build.

It will probably be months until a more stable version of `gdal 1.8` hits other mainstream releases.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that FWTools contains GDAL 1.8 or the develpment versions, it tends to be aimed at a more stable release.

The OSGEO4W installer does contain GDAL 1.8.  http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/  You can verify by looking in c:\OSGeo4W\bin.  You will see gdal18dev.dll  This comes with the normal warnings, it is a development version from trunk, it may change frequently.

David.

Comment: gdal 1.8 is not listed in the [package listing](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/wiki/PackageListing), or [current versions](http://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/versions.html) though presumably it will be eventually. Neither is the critical poppler dependency. I do have gdal18dev.dll in the bin directory but gdalinfo etc. from gdal-dev package do not seem to use it (gdalinfo geopdf-file.pdf gets an error). Question updated to say I'm interested in the end user utilities.